# Implementing .SentOnBehalfOfName

Tags: vba, outlook

My code:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
If Item.Class = olMail Then
    Set myItem = Item
End If
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Explorer
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient

Set oAccount = Application.ActiveExplorer
MsgBox (oAccount.CurrentFolder.Store)

If oAccount.CurrentFolder.Store = "account@outlook.com" Then
    MsgBox ("CC needs to be added")
    Set Recip = myItem.Recipients.Add("cc@cc.cc")
    Recip.Type = olCC
    Recip.Resolve
Else
    MsgBox ("no need to add CC")
End If
End Sub
```

I would like to add something like `myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sent@behalf.com"` into my code. Pasting it into my code does not work. I probably have to set something before.

I tried `myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sent@behalf.com"` but it does not do anything. It does not show any errors.

Comment: Search first. Based on that search put  myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sent@behalf.com"  into your code and if there is a problem ask about the problem.

Comment: I have been looking for few hours. i have already tried the myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sent@behalf.com" but it actually does not do anything. It does not show any errors also so i don't know what might be wrong. Anybody has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

This tricky SentOnBehalfOfName behaviour is described in previous posts.

```
Private Sub myItem_Open_SentonBehalf_Test()

Dim oExpl As Explorer
Dim myItem As mailitem

Set oExpl = ActiveExplorer
Set myItem = CreateItem(olMailItem)
' Do not display

If oExpl.CurrentFolder.store = "account@outlook.com" Then

    Debug.Print "myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName:" & "x " & myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName & " x"
    myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sent@behalf.com"
    Debug.Print "myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName:" & "x " & myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName & " x"

    ' be careful to put this after updating SentOnBehalfOfName
    myItem.Display
    ' Manually display the From field to see the updated entry

Else

    Debug.Print "Wrong path."

End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set myItem = Nothing
    Set oExpl = Nothing

End Sub
```